# Open Edit Page From History Page

Tags: google-app-maker

[Picture of a table of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y6Or.png)I want to open the edit form By clicking one row from the table in a different page. It have to be the same data field the user clicks.

Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "onClick" event and route it to a different page with the edit form. On the new page make sure to setup the same database and not a different datasource to open the same row and be able to edit it.

When you click the row.

[image]

It will open a new page to edit the same row clicked.

[image]